# UI5: How to use Association 'ariaLabelledBy'?

Tags: sapui5

In an `Input` control I'd like it labelled without use of a `Label` control, could the association `ariaLabelledBy` make labelling easier? How is this association implemented?

Comment: What is a "label" in your context? Why is the `Label` control not applicable? This question is a bit confusing. We need more information.

Comment: This is in attempt to reduce the number of controls I would need in my view. An Input is a box and a Label is the text next to it describing it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARIA (Accessible Rich Internet Applications) is a set of attributes that helps people with disabilities to access a web page e.g. with a screen reader.

so the "ariaLabelledBy" won't help you in your task.

Read more about [Accessibility in the UI5 Demo Kit](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/ff7cab1f271a4181a86e5aa5c2f8d421.html)